# Vue.js v-model for large html

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a custom wysiwyg text editor where you can add image in base64 so the output is super fat :)
The problem is when i try to initialize my component with the previously generated HTML :

```
<text-editor name="content" v-model="{{ $page->content }}"></text-editor>
```

The given error is unclear: `Error compiling template ... FULL TEMPLATE ... (found in <Root>)`

I tried to escape the html with `html_entity_decode`, `htmlentities`, `htmlspecialchars`, but it's not working better...

Comment: `$page->content` is probably introducing illegal characters that causes the markup to break, e.g. the `"` character.

Comment: That's why i try to use htmlspecialchars ;)

Comment: I suppose `}` are not escaped properly by that?

Comment: @LouisR `{{ }}` already escapes via htmlspecialchars.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks good to know

Comment: Why would `v-model` contain content? Isn't it just a variable name?

Comment: @Matt I use v-model for two way data binding, not sure to understand what you mean

Comment: @LouisR I have only seen `v-model` define which instance variable to use for the binding, e.g. `v-model="instanceVar"` - I've never seen it just hold content. Like `v-model="some content"` wouldn't work, what variable would it bind to?

Comment: @Matt Ok i got it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-model` is a syntactic sugar for:

```vue
<text-editor name="content" :value="{{ $page->content }}" @input="{{ $page->content }} = $event.target.value"></text-editor>
```

If you replace `{{ $page->content }}` for a HTML content (as PHP does) you will see that it does not work:

```
<text-editor name="content" :value="<div></div>" @input="<div></div> = $event.target.value"></text-editor>
```

Try passing a static value (without `:`) to the editor instead of using `v-model`:

```vue
<text-editor name="content" value="{{ $page->content }}"></text-editor>
```